# How to skip white lines while reading text file?

Tags: c, text-parsing

I want to read a text file line by line, but I'm not interested in the white lines. What nice way is there of skipping the blank lines? I know I could read a line, check if it's blank and free it if it is, and so on until I reach a good line, but I'm wondering if there's some other way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your method is good enough. Technically you should even check if it's only spaces :-) Note that if you are using `fscanf` (quite used in homework problems), white line skipping is "Included in the price" :-) AND you don't have to fight against "this line is bigger than my buffer, what should I do?"

Answer (score 0):

The general concept is fine ... you read in line by line and check to see if it has a non-whitespace character.  A fairly optimum way of checking for it is to use strspn ... for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_blank_line(const char *line) {
    const char accept[]=" \t\r\n"; /* white space characters (fgets stores \n) */
    return (strspn(line, accept) == strlen(line));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char line[256]; /* assuming no line is longer than 256 bytes */
    FILE *fp;

    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Need a file name\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if ( !fp ) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    while (!feof(fp)) {
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
        if (is_blank_line(line)) {
            continue;
        }
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If reading line by line use a simple check of '\n' (compiler will take care even if your real OS newline is \r\n).
If using fread to read whole file use strtok or strtok_r to split lines using sep='\n', empty lines will chopped out automatically.